# does "Enable advanced managed Google Play features" in Google Play have any additional impact

Tags: android, google-console-developer

I have an app running since some years. Now I get sometimes question from customers who would like to buy a group licence (School).

I found the option "Enable advanced managed Google Play features" in google play console and I don't dare to click on it :-)

I mean I am not sure if this will have any impact on my default behaviour of the app. Will the app still be purchasable by individual users, will rating still persist or be resetted. I would simply have the possibility to sell group license without ny other change .

Can someone confirm or explain how this will be ?

Comment: Ask Google Play developer support about it. They're live from Monday-Friday.